# Mediaplayer only have sound but not image error(-38 , 0)

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

I write a app to play video from Url using surfaceview and mediaplayer. When i played 3 video url, the next video url had only sound without image. And when i press back button to stop mediaplayer, sound still exists. I deleted app by task manager but sound still existed. Logcat throws bug below :

> 11-05 09:55:40.340: E/MediaPlayer(5077): stop called in state 0
>
> 11-05 09:55:40.340: E/MediaPlayer(5077): error (-38, 0)

My code :

```
public class ChannelDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channelid";
    private int channel_id;
    private TextView ab_title;
    private TextView mStartTime;
    private TextView mEndTime;
    private ImageView mPlayBtn;
//  private ProgressBar progress_loading;
    public String Urltoken;
    public String Urlvideo;
    private String userToken;
    private Utilities utils;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private RadioGroup rdgVideoBtn;
    private TappableSurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private RelativeLayout mBottomController;
    private Animation mAnimFadeOut;
    private RelativeLayout comment_container;
    private VideoView vd;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    /*
     * Switch screen between portrait and landscape
     */
    private OnClickListener mOnFullScreenBtnListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay();
            int orientation = display.getRotation();
            switch (orientation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    protected OnErrorListener mOnErrorListener = new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(mUpdateTimeTask);
            return false;
        }
    };
    /*
     * runnerable to display time on video
     */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long totalDuration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            if (totalDuration == 0 && !mEndTime.getText().equals("LIVE")) {
                mEndTime.setText("LIVE");
            }
            if (currentDuration > 0) {
                progress_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mStartTime.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);

        }
    };
    private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(OnPlayBtnListener);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
        }
    };
    /*
     * click to play video
     */
    private OnClickListener OnPlayBtnListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
                mPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(null);
                playVideo(videoUrl);
                return;
            }
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
                mPlayBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
            } else {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mPlayBtn.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
            }

        }
    };
    protected boolean isShowController;
    /*
     * an hien mediacontroller khi an vao man hinh player
     */
    private TapListener onTouchListener = new TapListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTap(MotionEvent event) {
            if (!isShowController) {
                mBottomController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mHideMediaController, 3000);
            }
        }
    };
    protected MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Callback mSurfaceHolderCallback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceholder;
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceholder);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            Log.d("surfaceCreated", "surfaceCreated");

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            Log.d("surfaceDestroyed", "surfaceDestroyed");

        }
    };
    private ProgressBar progress_loading;
    private ImageView mFullScreenBtn;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private RelativeLayout RLpager;
    private int width_pager,height_pager;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_channel_detail_fix);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        userToken = ((GlobalApp) getApplication()).getUserToken();
        utils = new Utilities();
        getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.ab_detail_custom);
        RLpager = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.comment_container);
        width_pager = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        height_pager = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        ab_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ab_title);
        if (extras != null) {
            channel_id = extras.getInt(ChannelDetailActivity.CHANNEL_ID);
        }
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_channel_detail);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mOnViewPagerChangeListener);
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,
                EPGByChannelFragment.class.getName(), extras));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,
                ChannelCommentFragment.class.getName(), extras));
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        comment_container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.comment_container);
        rdgVideoBtn = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_video_btn);
        rdgVideoBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mRadioGroupVideoListener);
        mSurfaceView = (TappableSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        mSurfaceView.addTapListener(onTouchListener);
        mStartTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_video_start_time);
        mEndTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_video_end_time);
        mPlayBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_video_play);
        progress_loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.player_progress);
        mFullScreenBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_video_small_zoom);
        mFullScreenBtn.setOnClickListener(mOnFullScreenBtnListener);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceHolderCallback);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mBottomController = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_info);
        mAnimFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getChannelInfo();
    }
    protected String videoUrl;
    private void getChannelInfo() {
        TimeTVApiCaller.getInstance().getChannel(channel_id, this,
                new AjaxCallback<ChannelInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void callback(String url, ChannelInfo object,
                            AjaxStatus status) {
                        if (object != null) {
                            videoUrl = object.getChannelUrls().get(0).getPath();
                            mPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(OnPlayBtnListener);
                            ab_title.setText(object.getName());
                            /*
                             * Auto play video
                             */
                            playVideo(videoUrl);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    protected void playVideo(String url) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mHideMediaController, 3000);
        mPlayBtn.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        progress_loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TimeTVApiCaller.getInstance().getChannelStream(url, this,
                new AjaxCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void callback(String url, String object,
                            AjaxStatus status) {
                        String path_stream = object.replace("\"", "");
                        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mOnErrorListener);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stuber
                                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path_stream);
                            mSurfaceView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            mSurfaceView.setDrawingCacheQuality(SurfaceView.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
                            mSurfaceView.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            mSurfaceView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                        mMediaPlayer
                                .setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
                        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                int width_SurfaceView = mSurfaceView.getWidth();
                                int height_SurfaceView = mSurfaceView.getHeight();
                                float boxWidth = width_SurfaceView;
                                float boxHeight = height_SurfaceView;
                                float videoWidth = mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
                                float videoHeight = mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
                                float wr = boxWidth/videoWidth;
                                float hr = boxHeight/videoHeight;
                                float ar = videoWidth/videoHeight;
                                if(wr > hr) width_SurfaceView = (int) (boxHeight * ar);
                                else height_SurfaceView = (int) (boxWidth / ar);
                                if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                    mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(width_SurfaceView, height_SurfaceView);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }

    TextView tv;


       @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
           int orientation = display.getRotation();
            if((event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
            {
                if(orientation == Surface.ROTATION_0)
                {
                    if(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    {
                        mMediaPlayer.stop();
                        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
                    }
                    finish();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        /*
         * switch to full screen when configuration changed
         * 
         * @see
         * android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onConfigurationChanged(android
         * .content.res.Configuration)
         */
        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                getActionBar().hide();
                comment_container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                getWindow().addFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                getActionBar().show();
                comment_container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    private Runnable mHideMediaController = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBottomController.startAnimation(mAnimFadeOut);
            mBottomController.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            isShowController = false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideMediaController);
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        super.onPause();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(RESULT_CANCELED);
        }
        finish();
        super.onStop();
    };
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**Can you help me to fix them ?**

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you everything you need to know. You are calling stop() while the MediaPlayer is idle.

After looking at your code on a PC instead of my phone, I feel pretty certain the problem is that you call `stop()` in the `OnCompletionListener`. That is completely unnecessary, as the media will have already stopped by the time it enters the callback. In fact, calling `stop()` would result in that callback being called in the first place.

You should be able to use the logcat to pinpoint the exact line in your code where the error occurs. It would be helpful if you post that info and point out what line the error refers to in the future.